# How to customize the popup time of iOS permission dialog for push notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I know that there is no possibility the permission dialog itself can be customized or disabled as long as the application is push enabled. But I wonder if its popup time can be postponed.

I have seen `Candy Crush Saga` does so.

The permission dialog does not appear until you reach a level when a customize dialog popup and ask if you would like to receive notifications from `Candy Crush Saga`, if you press OK, then comes the iOS standard permission dialog for push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` for the first time the dialog will be shown. So, don't call it until you need it.

Also, consider asking the user / informing the user what they will gain by accepting and asking if they're interested. If they are, use user defaults to record that and check that before calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` in the app delegate (for each startup). If the user is happy then set that flag in user defaults and call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` for the first time.

Comment: There is one thing that comes up to my mind. Does it mean that if I never call the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` method, then my App can not receive any push notification?

Comment: What a shame...I have to say...when you have a client insists no alert should be popped up and a boss insists that the app should support APNS push notification...

Comment: Not a shame, the user must be asked for permission. The client and management need to be informed of the realities of required user interaction and the consequences of their decisions. You can delay the display of the alert to a suitable time for the app, but you can't get APNS until after it has been shown and approved.